# проект на vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, backend, swagger

я начинающий во фронтенде, попал недавно в школу от IT комании, где нам дали проект.
Нас в команде трое(2 фронта и 1 бэк).

Так вот,я вообще не понимаю с чего начать,как сделать первые шаги,что обсудить с напарниками из команды,как вообще размышлять?Опыта 0,кучу вопросов и пробелов:(

Еще нам сказали обязательно использовать  **Swagger** и **Vue.js**

Вот сам проект, подскажите пожалуйста, с чего начать,в какую сторону глядеть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Охо-хо, вам нужен продакт менеджер, бизнес-аналист. Проект не очень-то и простой, начать нужно с создания задач, расстановки приоритетов задач, потом уже обсуждать детали реализации.

Comment: Начать стоит с того что вдвоем заставить бэкэндера сделать его часть хотя бы "на бумаге". А пока он трудится/прячется, изучайте документацию библиотек, решайте по среде сборки проекта и репо, и по разделению задач (работа с доской).

Comment: @yar85 А почему сначала бекендер должен делать свою часть?

Comment: @Pavel, так а кто если не бэкэндер будет БД под это счастье проектировать, и схемы OpenAPI генерировать/редактировать?.. уж явно не Пушкин. Но если я чего-то не понимаю, и фронтэндные моки можно нафигачить при отсутствии схем серверных ответов - буду рад узнать способы сделать это, поделись))

Comment: @yar85 ды в том то и дело, что я вообще ничего не знаю.В любом случае,спасибо за ответ)

Comment: @Pavel, на самом деле вообще очень странно что трейни/джунам ставят задачу которую молодые специалисты самостоятельно решать в принципе еще не умеют, и _не обязаны уметь_. В плане отношения к людям, это выглядит очень некрасиво со стороны той "IT компании" (если ее можно так назвать... я бы посоветовал поберечь время/здоровье, и сразу разорвать всякие отношения с ней).

Comment: @yar85 я еще даже не трейни и не джун, я пока просто попал на обучение от компании,где нам сразу дали этот проект,пока ничего не пояснив.Задал этот же вопрос ментору,он сказал что потом будет лекция,где все расскажет(через недели 2),но проект нужно сделать за месяц,а знаний вообще никаких!
И я вот еще хотел спросить у вас,я начал читать кучу инфы,которая возможно поможет мне с данной задачей(читал про API,Swagger,Vue).В общем многое не понял,запутался,да и вообще каша в голове, скажите это норма?А то я прям как-то расстроился и разочаровался в себе.

Comment: @Pavel, не могу судить о норме, и тем более о норме при обучении по книгам о веб-технологиях (а также по видео, или с преподавателем). Потому что по книгам я только общие основы программинга изучал, тогда как веб-вещи чисто по справочникам/докам/readme. Каша в голове случается имхо от того что более базовые (по отношению к изучаемым) вещи не были предварительно усвоены: если двигаться последовательно, то есть от фундаментальных основ "вверх" потихонечку-пошагово, таких эффектов практически не ощущается.

Comment: @yar85 Понял,спасибо большое!